# Div displayed correctly only when zoomed in or out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used the following structure to gain the same height as the smaller sibling.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="display: table; height:100%;">

<!-- child 1 - this should take the height of the smaller sibling -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height: inherit;
            overflow: scroll;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;"></div>

    <div class="col-md-8"></div> 

</div>
```

This worked fine when the browser (Chrome) was zoomed out. But when I reset the zoom, the scroll box shrunk.

Why is this occurring and how to get the initial display in the normal browser size?

I cannot reproduce the problem in jsFiddle but the code is as follows anyway:

https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/tvck2x6j/

Comment: Can you please add the fiddle for the same?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince I don't think I can reproduce the problem in jsfiddle, but the code is added anyway - updated the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use height like this way :

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="display:table;height:auto;"><!--either use fix height (height :500px;)-->

<!-- child 1 - this should take the height of the smaller sibling -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height: inherit;
            overflow: scroll;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;"></div>

    <div class="col-md-8"></div> 

</div>
```